# Getting the text content of an XML element without getting the text content of its child nodes

Tags: java, xml, text, svg

I am trying to import an image from an SVG format into the software I am working with.
For example, I have an SVG like this:

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
    <text>I Love SVG!
        <tspan> NOT! </tspan>"
    </text>
</svg>
```

When processing this data the 'text' element, I have TextString= "element.getTextContent()". This makes TextString = "I Love SVG! NOT!" when all I want is "I Love SVG!". So the getTextContent method returns the text from the element and its child elements, when I don't want to include the child elements text.

Is there a simple way to grab only the text content of an element without getting the child nodes text as well? Thanks

Comment: Use Xpath /svg/text/text(), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the element's child nodes using `element.getChildNodes()`. Any of them that have a node type of `Node.TEXT_NODE` are text nodes (there will often be more than one).

```
String textContent = "";
NodeList childNodes = element.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.length(); i++) {
    Node n = childNodes.item(i);
    if (n.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
       textContent += n.getNodeValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, but I want the text content for the original text element to only have the text of its element and not its children (e.g. the value of TextString for text to be " I Love SVG!", and TextString for tspan to be "Not!"

Comment: @DirtyProgrammer Yes, that's exactly what I'm showing you how to do. The `text` element in your example has two children that are text nodes. One is a text node containing `I Love SVG!` and some whitespace, and the other is a text node containing `"` and some whitespace (maybe that `"` was just a typo). Since there can be several, you should iterate through them, trim off the whitespace, and concatenate them together as needed.

Comment: What is happening if I concatenate them is I'll get the string: "I Love SVG! NOT! NOT!"

Comment: @DirtyProgrammer Did you include the `if (n.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)` part?

Answer (score 0):

Found out a solution to my problem, thanks for the suggestions JLRishe and kulatamicuda.

instead of TextString = element.getTextContent() ( which got the text from all child nodes as well as the original text node)

I used TextString = element.getFirstChild().getTextContent().

When using this I made sure the first child was actually a text node and not something like this:

```
<text><tspan>tspan text</tspan></text>
```